# Product-based binary numeration system

Tags: nt.number-theory, pr.probability, sequences-and-series, equidistribution

I am looking at the following binary numeration system:
$$x =\prod_{k=1}^\infty \Bigg(1+\frac{d_k(x))}{2^k}\Bigg), \quad d_k(x)\in \{0, 1\}.$$

The $d_k$'s are the digits, and $x$ is between $1$ (all digits equal to zero) and the maximum value when all digits are $1$. The digits are obtained using the greedy algorithm, in the same way you would for standard binary digits: $d_k(x)$, starting with $k=1$ is the maximum value between $0$ and $1$ so that the approximation based on the first $k$ factors is as large as possible, yet smaller or equal to $x$ at all times.

**My main question** is the following: are there any $x$ within the range in question, that can not be approximated exactly using this method? Clearly, if you remove $k=2,3,4$, that will be the case. But if you include all $k$, is it enough to cover all $x$? Note that a number may have two representations (like with continued fractions) but the greedy algorithm can only produced one, called the *standard* representation.

In the end, I am also very interested in this: if you pick up a number randomly (say $x$ uniformly distributed on the domain), how are the digits distributed? I seems that as $k\rightarrow\infty$, $d_k(x)$ is zero or one, each with probability $\frac{1}{2}$. And there is no correlation between successive digits, at the limit. Not sure how easity it is to prove/disprove these statements.